# Batch file variable overwrite

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am creating a batch file to run a command. I set the command as follows.

```
set my_command=some_command %out_file%
```

I then run (or intended to) the command with different out_file variable

```
set out_file=[some_dir_1]
%my_command%

set out_file=[some_dir_2]
%my_command%
```

When I run the batch file, it runs my_command with out_file=[some_dir_2] twice, instead of running the first time with out_file=[some_dir_1]

Is there a way I can run the same command with different var reset everytime?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set my_command=some_command ^^!out_file^^!
set out_file=[some_dir_1]
echo %my_command%

set out_file=[some_dir_2]
echo %my_command%
pause
```

This works by setting the value of `my_command` to `some_command !out_file!`, so with escaped exclamation marks. When you use `echo !my_command!`, you'll see it contains the exclamation marks. However, when you use `%my_command%`, the exclamation marks get read after the % signs, so it sees another variable to expand.

You can imagine batch parsing order like this:

1. expand variables like `%var%` to their value
2. expand variables like `!var!` to their value

So first, the parser sees

> %my_command%

which get turned into

> some_command !out_file!

However, it **then** (it's called **delayed** expansion for a reason) starts checking for exclamation marks and changes that to

> some_command [some_dir_2]

**EDIT**

Just noticed that this also works:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "my_command=some_command ^!out_file^!"
set "out_file=[some_dir_1]"
echo %my_command%

set "out_file=[some_dir_2]"
echo %my_command%
pause
```

Comment: @ScottF added better explanation.

Comment: @ScottF improved it a bit.

Comment: Another method: `set my_command=some_command %%out_file%%` & `set out_file=[some_dir_1]` & `call echo %my_command%`

Comment: @Aacini does call cause a command to parse two times? That's neat.